# apt update error: "Writing more data than expected"

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I'm running Linux Mint 18 (Sarah) and today I got the following update error:

```
# sudo apt update

Ign:1 http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/linuxmint/packages sarah InRelease
...
Err:12 http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Writing more data than expected (863064 > 862917)
Ign:13 http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Fetched 204 kB in 3s (53.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Writing more data than expected (863064 > 862917)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

However, the old school solution as shown in various (duplicate) posts is not working and without any effect. (I.e. same output as above.)

```bsh
sudo apt -o Acquire::https::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True update
```

**What is the problem and how can it be resolved?**

Comment: 2.5 years later, >1k views, and still not a single answer!? Highly unusual for SE.